# ng-blur is not triggered when I lose focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i've been trying to be able to change the title of a playlist by double clicking on it.

I'm using ng-blur to know when i lose focus on the edit, but the doneEditing function is never called. (editTitle and done editing just set playlist.editing to true and false and console.log editing and done editing).

.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Playlist</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">    

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <article ng-app>
      <div class="todo-wrapper" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <h2 ng-hide="playlist.editing" ng-dblclick="editTitle(playlist)">{{playlist.title}}</h2> 
        <input ng-show="playlist.editing" ng-model="playlist.title" ng-blur="doneEditing(playlist)" autofocus />
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done"/>
            <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form>
          <input class="add-input" placeholder="I need to..." type="text" ng-model="formTodoText" />
          <button class="add-btn" ng-click="addTodo()"><h2>Add</h2></button>
        </form>
        <button class="clear-btn" ng-click="clearCompleted()">Clear completed</button>
      </div>
    </article>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

.js

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.todos = [
    {text:'Movie1', done:false},         
    {text:'Movie2', done:false}
  ];
  $scope.playlist = {title: "New Playlist", editing:false};

  $scope.getTotalTodos = function () {
    return $scope.todos.length;
  }; 

  $scope.addTodo = function () {
    $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.formTodoText, done:false});
    $scope.formTodoText = '';
  };

  $scope.clearCompleted = function () {
        $scope.todos = _.filter($scope.todos, function(todo){
            return !todo.done;
        });
  };

  $scope.editTitle = function (playlist) {
      playlist.editing = true;
  };

  $scope.doneEditing = function (playlist) {
      playlist.editing = false;
  };

}
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here, because the examples I've found on fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/davekr/F7K63/43/) are working fine using those lines.

PS : I've tested to run the code on both Firefox and Chrome, the doneEditing function has never been called.

Edit : Uploaded the full .html and .js files

Comment: More Javascript Code Please

Comment: Uploaded the .js part, is that enough ?

Comment: No. Whole JS Code please

Comment: Uploaded the full .html and .js files !

Comment: @GuillaumeRoche-Bayard did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: No sorry, the .html version i uploaded wasn't up-to-date, the ng-model didn't fixed it. And the I have console.log() in my function but i didn't put them here because they don't matter really to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `ng-model="playlist.title"`to the input tag

```
<h2 ng-hide="playlist.editing" ng-click="editTitle(playlist)">{{playlist.title}}</h2> 
<input ng-show="playlist.editing" ng-model="playlist.title" ng-blur="doneEditing(playlist)" autofocus />
```

And if you add `console.log("foo");` to the `doneEditing` function you can see that it is working correctly

## EDIT

Here is a plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/LoW9nkhYO5BIaOzuaxOX?p=preview

Update AngularJS to newest version or at least 1.2 <

Comment: Sorry my .html wasn't up to date yet, the ng-model didn't fix it (i tried it already !)

Comment: Edited answer check the link

Comment: Ok ! Thanks ! Didn't know that could be a trouble !

Comment: Haha small things. Added the version to my answer. Happy coding

Comment: Thanks again, I was just wondering why is the autofocus not working ? When i double click, the focus should be on the input right ? Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Add a timeout after setting the playlist.editing to true `setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("foo").focus();
      }, 100);`